# Azure Search Synonym Maps not returning expected results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Hello Azure Search Team - 
                         I am trying to get Azure Search Synonyms to work but it does not seem to be working for me. The things that I have already done:
    1) I added the synonym map:

```
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D77E66017FAAF9\"",
            "name": "bodytypes-synonymmap",
            "format": "solr",
            "synonyms": "fafafafafa, service van, utility van => Service Utility Van"
        }
```

2) Then I associated that map to the index field that holds the data:

```
            "name": "BodyType",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null,
            "synonymMaps": [
                "bodytypes-synonymmap"
            ]
        }
```

3) I am testing the search with the test term "fafafafafa" and I do not get any results back, but I do get search result back for "Service Utility Van". That leads me to believe that the Search Synonyms are not working for some reason.

More info: I am on the free tier of the service, does that make a difference?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was adding an @ symbol in front of the synonym map string which made into a string literal which included the "\n" newline symbol as part of the replaced search term and so I was seeing no results. So it was my bad!